# put html value into onClick()

Tags: javascript, html

```
var content;

function listReply2() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "${contextPath}/comment/listJson.do?bno=${article.articleNO}",
    success: function(result) {

      var output = "<table>";

      for (let i in result) {

        output += "<tr>";
        output += "<td>" + result[i].writer;
        output += "(" + changeDate(result[i].regdate) + ")</td>";
        output += "<td >" + result[i].content + "</td>";

        if (member_id != null) {
          output += "<td><input type='button' id ='rno' value='mod' onclick='commentMod(result[i].content)'/>";
          output += "<input type='button' value='delete' onclick=''/></td>";
        }
        output += "</tr>";

      }
      output += "</table>";
      $("#comment").html(output);

    }
  });
```

I want to put HTML value `result[i].content` into onClick function so that I can move the value when I press the mod button.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried implementing the actual reference rather than a string reference to the variable? Like `onclick='commentMod(' + result[i].content + ')'` or a string template literal like `onclick=commentMod(${result[i].content})`? Because you wrote the reference as a string, each element will have an commentMod function that literally has the words "result[i].content" being passed to it.

Comment: organize your code, this might help you: https://jsfiddle.net/51j4xd6o/2/

Comment: @MatthewWolman i figure out by getting the value as id , then toss it to the function. var abc = result[i].content;  <input type='button' id =" + abc + " value='mod' onclick='commentMod(this.id)'/>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that functions generated by the HTML parser for `onEventName` attributes are not created in function scope. As a result,

```
 onclick='commentMod(result[i].content)
```

will try to find `result` and `i` in global scope rather than in the function scope of the `success` handler. A solution that involves generating table elements using `document.createElement` calls and adding event listeners in JavaScript could be devised but lacks the simplicity of HTML generation.

One way of generating the handlers in HTML could be to insert the value of `result[i].content` into the `onclick` attribute value after escaping it so as not to interfere with HTML parsing and then unescape the string before calling `commentMod`.

Note the snippet example  simply uses *`escape`* and `unescape` since the string being encoded is **not** part of a URL.

```js
"use strict";
let result = [{content: "I'm < than a teapot & > than a coffee \"jar\""}];
let i = 0;

let html = `<span onclick='alert(unescape("${escape(result[i].content)}"))'>Click Me</span>`;
document.body.innerHTML = html;
console.log( html);
```

Hence try replacing

```
output += "<td><input type='button' id ='rno' value='mod' onclick='commentMod(result[i].content)'/>";
```

with

```
output += `<td><input type='button' id ='rno' value='mod'
    onclick='commentMod(unescape("${escape(result[i].content)}"))'/>`;
```